# Cell Column Excel Formula To Do Comparison of Values

Tags: excel, formula, conditional-formatting

I want to use Conditional Formatting in Excel to determine my cell's color. I was trying to use the Less Than some value then red, greater than some value, then green.

But I wanted to make it much more variable as I need to apply this to a multitude of cells. I found the vlookup field, and made this:
`="VLOOKUP(""6_0"",$A$1:$G$16,CELL(""col""),FALSE)"`
It looks for 6_0 in the rows $A$1 through $G$16. Then it grabs the value in the column specified. I attempted to specify the column through CELL("col"), but that just specifies the currently active cell, meaning my conditional formatting changes every time I click a new cell.

This brings me to my question, how do I get something like Cell("col") that is based of the cell that the formula is applied to not the active cell?

Comment: please share your sample data and I will help you with that!

Comment: Using COLUMN() seems correct, but isn't working for some reason... VLOOKUP("6_0",$A$1:$G$16,COLUMN(),FALSE)

Comment: using a google spreadsheet is highly appreciated, please create one and share the link.

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/10VRZ-NWdAo7ySdAA3T_eGUl7C36kINHC6AGlFLx4itc/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: this is why I asked you to create a google spreadsheet, it's quick and easy :)

Comment: it will help others as well to answer your question very quickly because they won't need to spend time in re-organizing your data first!

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/10VRZ-NWdAo7ySdAA3T_eGUl7C36kINHC6AGlFLx4itc/edit

Comment: cool, I can see you've got seven columns... where you want the conditional formula to be applied?

Comment: It looks like I got it with the COLUMN() option, but Excel had added unnecessary quotes when I copy pasted it. Notice the double quotes in Problem description.

Comment: okay, and how do you compare the vlookup's result for coditional formatting? I mean if the vlookup results some data then what? or if it doesn't then what?

Answer (score 0):

Once I used the COLUMN() function, I just had extra quotes from copy pasting things. What got it working was this:

```
VLOOKUP("6_0",$A$1:$G$16,COLUMN(),FALSE)
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/GRDpo.png
The numbers are theoretical, and it compares them to the *_0 rows to determine color). Had to write a vba script to get the color to transfer to the 3d graph.